# CSS Media Type and Query is not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I am having this CSS style, which i am trying to run on chrome v28, Firefox v222 and IE8:

```
html, body{
            margin: 36px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
            html, body{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #page {
                margin: 20px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
```

and as a markup I add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body><div id="page"></div></body>
</html>
```

Just want to understand why it is not changing color to red if I minimize the window.

Any Help will be great help.

Thanks
Raja

Comment: change this "@media screen and (max-width: 768px)" to this "@media (max-width: 768px)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#page` has no content thus it has `height:0px;` Try the following: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WjqSM/))

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    html, body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #page {
        margin: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%; /* set the height */
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

As for the addition to the question - changing the background - You will have to reverse the order of the CSS like this:

```
<style> 

html, body{ 
    margin: 36px; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
} 
body{ background-color: black; } /* This should be first for the media query to override */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){ 
    html, body{ margin: 20x; } 
    body{ background-color: red; } /* When the media query is applied this overrides the previous rule */
} 

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did work. But, what If I remove div and want to change the background-color of body based on media query. Like:                                                       `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  html, body{
   margin: 20x;
  }
    
  body{
   background-color: red;
  }
 }
 
  html, body{
            margin: 36px;
            width: 100%;
   height: 100%;            
        }
  
  body{
   background-color: black;
  }
 </style>
<head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @RAJAMALIK upadted with new requirement